# Can I use "out of order" like this?

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

1. The elevator out of order will be fixed. (without "which is")
2. She put my computer out of order.

Can I use "out of order" like this?

I'm confused because there are like, "He put me at ease," or, "He put me at risk," or, "She put me out of action."

Comment: *Out of **action*** is a different idiomatic usage. Just because they "look similar" to you doesn't mean native speakers treat them interchangeably. *Out of order* is for toilets and lifts, *out of action* is more for *people* who are *temporarily unable* to do things. Different people will have slightly different views about *specific* usages anyway. But there's no real shortcut based on recognizing "patterns" in such idiomatic usages - mostly you just have to learn them in isolation. Of course, no-one says you *must* use them at all. A *faulty* elevator (that *doesn't work*) is all you need.

Comment: And  to make it even more complicated, if "out of order" is used in the sense "no longer properly sorted", e.g. alphabetically, one could say "Don't shuffle the papers. You'll put them out of order."  So it's a semantic issue.  When out of order means "broken, in need of repair" you can't say "You put it out of order". The verb "put" and that state are incompatible.  Similarly, something can "make you sick" but it can't "put you sick", though it can "put you in the hospital".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samples:

The elevator out of order will be fixed. (without "which is") [buzzer]

She put my computer out of order. [buzzer]

Possible Fixes:
The elevator, which is out of order, will be fixed.
OR
The out-of-order elevator will be fixed.
OR
The elevator is broken down and will be fixed tomorrow.

"which is out of order" is a non-defining or non-restrictive or parenthical clause that provides additional information without changing the base sentence.

- She made my computer not work.
- My computer is not working and she did that.

"out of order" is usually used for things like: bathroom toilets, washing machines, dish washers, cars. Computers are not viewed like other machines. Though out of order can conceivably be used for computers.

- My computer is out of order and I'm taking it to be fixed.

More usual is something like:

- My computer is on the fritz and she did that.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is acceptable if written on a notice and stuck on the elevator door; it's brief but understandable.

> *The elevator out of order will be fixed.*

Add a dash to replace “which is”

> The elevator–out of order, will be fixed [tomorrow].

A smart solution was offered by @Lambie:

> *The out-of-order elevator will be fixed [tomorrow]*.

Note that the idiom, which is a prepositional phrase, “out of order” is joined by hyphens to preserve its meaning.

Another solution would be:

> The elevator **is** out of order. Repairs begin tomorrow.

If the OP is interested in idiomatic and natural-sounding  sentences then the second example is much less common

> *She **put** my computer **out of order**.*

We don't normally say someone ***puts*** [something] ***out of order***, which suggests that the act was not accidental. It is more idiomatic to say *someone* **broke** *something*.

> *She broke my computer*

If we wanted to wedge in "out of order" with *computer*, we could say

- My computer **was out of order** when I got it back from Alice/Bob.

But it would be more common and idiomatic to say

- My computer **wasn't working** (or *stopped working*) when I got it back from Alice.

#### What type of machines go “out of order“?

Machines are not “put out of order” they are either **[in working order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/working?q=in%20working%20order)** or **out of order**. And not all machines are collocated with the expression! The idiom is more likely used with large machinery destined for the general public or the workplace.

- [vending machines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vending-machine)
- [coffee machines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coffee-machine),
- [cash machines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cash-machine) or ATMs
- lifts or elevators
- photocopiers or copy machines,

Comment: I don't think the first is acceptable at all.

Comment: @Lambie It's fine on a notice. Informal language is acceptable in this case. I would just leave it as **Out of order** in a notice. When would anyone write an email about fixing an elevator at some undetermined point in the future as suggested by the OP? Maybe to the administrator, maybe? I doubt it.